# Kotlin, Cucumber and Selenium - Kotlin not able to interact with element(s)

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, kotlin, cucumber

I'm trying to create a simple test in IntelliJ, using Kotlin instead of Java, along with Cucumber and Selenium. However, it doesn't seem to be as straight-foward as I thouht. I've installed Kotlin and configured it for the project, and there are no error messages related to that.

However, just a simple thing like clicking on a radio button i a list seems to be difficult to achieve in Kotlin. There is no error message; The click just doesn't happen.

The Cucumber line:

```
Og jeg har et konkret boligprosjekt
```

The (Java) step definition:

```
@Og("^jeg har et konkret boligprosjekt$")
public void jegHarEtKonkretBoligprosjekt() {
    //oppforePage.velgKonkretBoligprosjekt();          <-- Java
    OppforePageK.Companion.velgKonkretBoligprosjekt(); <-- Kotlin
}
```

The Java Page Object (which works as expected):

```
@Slf4j
public class OppforePage {
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

    private static WebElement lblsokerOmboligprosjekt;

    private ExtendedWebDriver driver;


    public OppforePage() {
        this.driver = Browser.extendedDriver();
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    void velgKonkretBoligprosjekt() { lblsokerOmboligprosjekt.click(); }

...
```

The Kotlin Page Object (which doesn't work):

```
import no.husbanken.e2e.rammeverk.selenium.driver.ExtendedWebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory

class OppforePageK() {
    companion object {
        var driver: ExtendedWebDriver = Browser.extendedDriver()

        @FindBy(id = "lblsokerOmboligprosjekt")
        private val lblsokerOmboligprosjekt: WebElement? = null

        init {
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)
        }

        fun velgKonkretBoligprosjekt() {
            lblsokerOmboligprosjekt?.click()
        }
    }
}
```

(I've removed some of the obvious imports etc.)

When Kotlin tries to click the button with the velgKonkretBoligprosjekt() method, nothing happens on the page. There is no error message, however, and the test continues and fails on a later step because the button wasn't clicked.

Any ideas? I know it should be possible to use Kotlin for this, but I seem to be constantly running into small walls where I cannot figure out why seeminling small and simple things just doesn't work like I think the will.

Comment: In Java class, your driver isn't static. Why do you keep everything in kotlin class in companion object?

Comment: I prefer static methods for this sort of thing, so maybe that's the reason. I'm not sure :-)

Comment: HowEVER...it works when I remove the companion object and instead instantiate the Kotlin object. Why is that? Why doens't it work with a static call?

Comment: Are selenium server logs reachable? Maybe you can derive some meaning from them?

Comment: Hm. Those aren't allways easy to get anything useful out of. Well: I probably wouldn't have thought of trying non-static without your comment, so thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
@FindBy(id = "lblsokerOmboligprosjekt")
        private val lblsokerOmboligprosjekt: WebElement? = null
```

I'd say this is the problem. `val`s can't be reassigned, try changing it to `private var`, otherwise nothing happens, since your WebElement is null

EDIT: It seems that the issue was connected to the logic being wrapped in a companion object

Comment: Good point, and a silly mistake by me, However, it doesn't seem to make any difference. However, if I remove the companion object and instantiate the class instead, it works. Why?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with neither Cucumber nor Selenium, so I'm not sure what happens there. I'd say that most likely the lblsokerOmboligprosjekt's value doesn't get there for some reason :)